# Pointer logic causing an access violation

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, data-structures

One of my program methods to add a contact is giving the following error when executing:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00111deb in G00290342.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000050.
```

I have researched the error and found that it is caused by accessing memory already in use.I have narrowed it down to the pointer logic in my readFile method that is causing the 'curr' variable to be NULL.

The code it is breaking at is here:

```
while(curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;

    }
```

This is the complete method for reference:

```
int addContact(struct contact *theList)
{
    struct contact *newContact, *curr;
    char fn[15],sn[15],ph[15],cmpy[15],eml[15];

    //create the new structure
    newContact = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    if(newContact == NULL)
    {

        return(0);

    }
    //find the end of list
    curr = theList;
    //scroll through the list
    while(curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;

    }
    //now have the last contact and the new one here
    printf("\nEnter a surname: ");
    gets(newContact->sname);

    printf("\nEnter a first name: ");
    gets(newContact->fname);

    printf("\nEnter a phone: ");
    gets(newContact->phone);

    printf("\nEnter a company: ");
    gets(newContact->company);

    printf("\nEnter an email: ");
    gets(newContact->email);

    //add the new contact to the end of the list

    curr->next = newContact;
    newContact->prev = curr;
    newContact->next = NULL;
    return(0);


}//end addContact
```

This is the main method where I'm reading the test file:

```
main()
{
    int sts,iChoice;
    struct contact *ptrList, *head;

    //head of sorted list
    struct contact *srtdList;

    srtdList = NULL;
    ptrList = NULL;

    ptrList = readFile("test.csv",ptrList);
    head = ptrList;

    /////menu for options
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\t\tWelcome to BV Contact Organizer\n\n");
    printf("\n\n\t\tEnter a number ranging from 1 to 6 for options.\n\n");
    printf("\n\t\t1. Search");
    printf("\n\t\t2. Add");
    printf("\n\t\t3. Sort");
    printf("\n\t\t4. Remove");
    printf("\n\t\t5. Edit");
    printf("\n\t\t6. Exit");
    printf("\n\n\t\tEnter your menu choice: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &iChoice);

    // user enters one of 6 values:
    // Search,add,sort,remove,exit or edit contacts


    switch(iChoice)
    {

        case 1:     // Add
        {
            sts = addContact(head);
            sts = writeListToFile("test.csv",head);
            while(ptrList != NULL)
            {
                printf("\n%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",ptrList->sname,ptrList->fname,ptrList->phone,ptrList->company,ptrList->email);
                ptrList = ptrList->next;

            }

            break;
        }
        case 2:     // Sort
        {
            //return the head of the sorted list to here
            srtdList = sortList(head,srtdList);
            head = srtdList;
            if(srtdList != NULL)
            {

                printf("\n\nSorted List");
                while(srtdList != NULL)
                {
                    printf("\n%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",srtdList->sname,srtdList->fname,srtdList->phone,srtdList->company,srtdList->email);
                    srtdList = srtdList->next;

                }

                sts = writeListToFile("testSort.csv",head);

            }
            else
            {
                printf("nothing to print");

            }
            printf("\n\n\n");
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
        case 3:     // Exit
        {
            printf("\n\nProgram exiting!...");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("\n\nInvalid menu choice,please choose a number ranging from 1 to 6!...");
        }

    }//end of switch


    return(iChoice);

} // end of main
```

This is the struct contact definition as requested:

```
struct contact {
        char sname[15];
        char fname[15];
        char phone[15];
        char company[15];
        char email[15];
        struct contact *prev;
        struct contact *next;
};
```

This is the method used to readFile and is causing the problem:

```
struct contact *readFile(char * FName,struct contact *ptrList)
{

struct contact *head, *newContact;
FILE *fptr;
char oneLine[60];
char *sname, *fname, *phone,*company, *email;

head = ptrList;

fptr = fopen(FName,"r");

if(fptr == NULL)
{
    printf("\nCant open file!");
    return(ptrList);

}

fgets(oneLine, 55, fptr);
while(!feof(fptr))
{
    fgets(oneLine, 55, fptr);
    if(oneLine[strlen(oneLine)-1] == '\n')
    {
        oneLine[strlen(oneLine)-1] = '\0';

    }

    sname = strtok(oneLine,",");
    fname = strtok(NULL,",");
    phone = strtok(NULL,",");
    company = strtok(NULL,",");
    email = strtok(NULL,",");

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
        ptrList = head;
        strcpy(head->sname,sname);
        strcpy(head->fname,fname);
        strcpy(head->phone,phone);
        strcpy(head->company,company);
        strcpy(head->email, email);

        head->prev = NULL;
        head->next = NULL;


    }
    else
    {

        newContact = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
        head->next = newContact;
        newContact->prev = head;
        newContact->next = NULL;
        //copy the data to the new one
        strcpy(head->sname,sname);
        strcpy(head->fname,fname);
        strcpy(head->phone,phone);
        strcpy(head->company,company);
        strcpy(head->email,email);

        //move down the list so that the head variable
        //points to the last contact
        head = newContact;

    }

  }//end while

  fclose(fptr);
  return(ptrList);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `curr` is not `NULL` because that is what it looks like. Looks like some offset from a `NULL` here `0x00000050`

Comment: You are not checking "theList" for NULL.  If it were, your while loop would fail.  At least ASSERT it.

Comment: you might want to check `theList` for NULL prior to any attempt at walking it, since your newly allocated node should become new list head if it is. Further, since the value reported is not `0x00000000`, it is highly likely you're not properly initializing your list head to NULL in the first place, another error in logic. Finally, you need to either pass the list head in by address (meaning double pointer) or always return the real list head as a function result, or you'll never get the external list head set correctly.

Comment: And.. as if that isn't enough, **don't use `gets()`**. That function is so bad security-wise it has been deprecated from the language and will not be included in the next standard. Use `fgets()` instead. Since you're updating your question post, is there any chance you can also add the structure definition of `struct contact` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I think it is `0x00000050` because that is the offset of `next` in the `contact` object.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour you're very-much correct, and I stand (actually I'm sitting) corrected. Thanks!

Comment: can u also show the code for `readfile` method

Comment: Ya I have added the struct definition of contact now.

Comment: Turns out it's because 'curr' is not initialized.What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: @WhozCraig Unless it snuck back in between N1570 and the actual standard, it has already been removed: "— removed the gets function (<stdio.h>)" (Hooray, Cheer, :D )

Comment: @DanielFischer Srsly? woot!

Comment: @WhozCraig,I added this curr = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact)); to initialise but im still getting an error.Could you give me a snippet of how to sort out my readFile method?Thanks

Comment: @WhozCraig Yep, looking at `stdio.h`, I can read: "The function has been officially removed in ISO C11.  This opportunity is used to also remove it from the GNU feature list.  It is now only available when explicitly using an old ISO C, Unix, or POSIX standard. GCC defines _GNU_SOURCE when building C++ code and the function is still
in C++11, so it is also available for C++." (Proof that C is the better language ;)

Comment: I could, but you don't learn when you don't think. So consider this: After each insertion what do you want your head pointer to point *to*? *Equally important*, where should the the old head pointer be placed to ensure you can still reach the prior list? (hint for both questions: when finished inserting the new node, your *new* head pointer will be one hop away from the old list content, and zero hops away from the new node, assuming your building your list in reverse). Hmmm..

Comment: @WhozCraig you want the head pointer to point to the head of the list? and the old pointer should be placed at the end of the old list? am I right..am I right?

Comment: @user2307951 As you seem to have tried to implement it, it appears you want the `head` pointer in `readFile()` to point to the last-node-inserted, its `prev` pointing to the node from the old `head` pointer, and the old `head` pointer's `next` pointing to the new node. If you want to insert new nodes at the beginning of the list, then you want the new node's `next` pointer to point to the old `head` pointer, and the old `head` pointers `prev` pointing to the new node. In **both** caes, you want `head` pointing to the last node inserted no matter what.

Comment: @WhozCraig so I think I got it now and correct me if im wrong but to set a contact when the head in't null would be like this: `head->next = newContact;` `newContact->prev = head;` `newContact->next = ptrList;` and point the head to the last node inserted which would be `head = newContact;`

Comment: @WhozCraig the previously mentioned edit to my code didn't work either.I dont what I'm doing wrong as I have set the pointers to the old head pointer as you have said..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are assigning `curr` to `theList` without any `NULL` checks:

```
curr = theList;
```

so when you get to the `while` if `curr` is indeed `NULL` then you will have access violation when you attempt to to do `curr->next`:

```
while(curr->next != NULL)
{
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

Comment: That was my answer :) - yours in prettier though +1

Comment: Ya I just added a null check on curr = theList; and it has given me the error 'curr' is being used without being initialized.My second question is how do I remedy this?

Comment: @user2307951 It is hard to tell but my guess would be that in `readFile` you are failing to open the file and you return `ptrList` which is `NULL` but `addContact` should have logic in place to create `head` if it is not initialized as WhozCraig said you need to pass `theList` as a double pointer for that to work.

Comment: Reading `readFile()`, what happens when you pass an existing list into the function? `head` will initially be set to that `ptrList`, which presumably has a `next` pointing to the rest of the list. Then, on the first node read, `head->next = newContact`  orphans everything past the initial `ptrList` node, thereby losing (and leaking) those nodes. You might want to fix that as well, or don't bother allowing the function to amend an existing list and just take out `ptrList`. As currently written, it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would implement this? So it is stemming from my 'readFile' method..If I take out 'ptrList' how would I go about this?

Comment: If I remove `head->next = newContact` this will correct the problem? Or do I have to make further adjustments in the method? @WhozCraig

Comment: @user2307951 Is it your intent to build the list from the end onward? If so, you need to move the head pointer to the last position of the incoming list *before* beginning you loop (which, of course, requires you to first test the incoming list for NULL before walking it). Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: yes that is my intent..so I should set head->prev? @WhozCraig

Comment: There's little point in me trying to explain it to you further without code, but there are *ample* samples of double-linked lists on the web.  [See it live here](http://ideone.com/1QJVmo)

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for continuing to help out on this one once I left.

Answer (score 0):

It says `Access violation reading location 0x00000050` So you are trying to read a memory location which is actually some junk value. Trace theList value from the beginning, Also Wherever you are allocating memory, immediately do a `memset(newContact,0,sizeof(struct contact))`. After all these, if you still facing the problem, provide the code, there might be logic issue

Comment: I tried the memset snippet but I'm getting an error saying that argument of type contact is incompatible with type int.I have updated my question with my main method above where I'm reading the list.

Comment: Sorry typo :) in the memset

Comment: I added the memset snippet again after mem allocation.What exactly does this snippet do?

Comment: If you add the null check, you are making sure you can detect an empty list, or end of list correctly. And at the end of the method, you have added `newContact->next = NULL;` which makes this possible. Now memset will set the entire memory allocated by malloc to 0. So even if you had missed it or some other place you might be still missing it, the memset had compensated for that, and your null check would still work. Basically it's a fail safe mechanism.

Comment: cool I just tested it there and it says 'curr' is not initialised.How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my pointers in the readFile method.Can you spot where the logic error is?

Answer (score 0):

```
curr = theList;    
 while(curr->next != NULL)
 {
    curr = curr->next;

}
```

the issue also might happen if last element in `theList` is `not null` and pointing to garbage memory location

Comment: Okay,I fixed that problem and it turns out it's my readFile method as the pointers aren't initialized correctly.Can you spot where my pointers are messed up?

Comment: There are multiple problems in the above code. 
1.in `else block` of `readFile` you should assign new values of name phone company etc to `newContact` not to `head`.
2. You are never assigning anything to `ptrList` before returning it. so `method` always returns `null`. This causes memory issue