# C++ crash on getting pointer

Tags: c++

I'm guessing it's leading nowhere, a NULL pointer or something, however I'm checking just that beforehand

Both of these snippets crash:

```
//Snippet 1
DWORD *address = (DWORD*)(base + 0x54);

if (address)
    address = (DWORD*)(*address + 0xC);

if (address)
    address = (DWORD*)(*address + 0x8);   //crashes here


//Snippet 2
DWORD address = *(DWORD*)(base + 0x54);

if (address)
    address = *(DWORD*)(address + 0xC);

if (address)
    address = *(DWORD*)(address + 0x8);   //crashes here
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's impossible to tell. Everything you wrote might be undefined behaviour. No telling without knowing what the initial value of `base` is.

Comment: I made a rule of thumb many years ago: if I have a pointer to a pointer to a pointer it's time to rethink what I'm doing. This code has yet another layer, so it's even less comprehensible.

Comment: I'm iterating through an array of adresses and call this method every runthrough, base is the current address. What's wrong with multilevel pointers?

Comment: Without a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) there is not much help we can give you here, unfortunately.

Comment: If you write stupid code expect stupid results.

Comment: Wow, I'm getting much hate here, maybe I should've mentionend that it's an (supposed to be) injected dll that reads memory from another process, no way around them multipointers...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer logic causing an access violation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176586/pointer-logic-causing-an-access-violation)

Answer (score 1):

Access violation!

You're touching some parts of memory which probably is forbidden to your program. Dereferencing a pointer which points to an unknown place is undefined behavior.